# Как добавить скрипт для Tilemap

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Я только начинаю изучать юнити. Узнал про такую штуку, как tilemap. Я могу построить какие-либо объеуты с его помощью. А если мне нужно использовать какой-то объект со скриптом, что в таком случае делать? Скрипт я не могу повесить ни на сам tilemap, ни на его объекты. Изпользовать перфабы в tilemap я тоже не могу. Кто знает, как решить, подскажите, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html) можно строить уровни(так например вы можете построить 2 тайлмапа один с [boxcollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/class-BoxCollider.html)(стены), а другой без (фон, пол и тд), но [объекты](https://unityhub.ru/manual/GameObjects) лучше размещать не в tilemap, а на самой сцене как и [tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html). И если вы разместите [объект](https://unityhub.ru/manual/GameObjects), на самой сцене, вы сможете прикрепить к нему скрипт.